# Display 'closed' if IS_CLOSED is true

Tags: mysql, sql

If `is_closed` is returned as true from a query, how do I tell the query to set `closing_time` to `closed`, instead of displaying what is really in the row... such as `23:00:00` ?

I tried

```
AND IF(is_closed = 1, 1, 0) closing_time = 'closed'
```

but that resulted in

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'closing_time = 'closed' GROUP BY venues.VENUE_NAME' at line 27

Thanks!

**edit** `closing_time` is a date field.

Comment: If `closing_time` is a `date` field, it can only ever return a `date` value, not just any string.

Comment: Mhm, that means I have to pass the date onto a variable, and manipulate that instead?

Comment: Well, you could convert the date to a string and show that (or 'closed'), but you might want to consider handling this in your application instead of the database.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt if `closing_time` is a date field, it can't be set as `'closed'` but it can be displayed as `'closed'`, i think is this what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your field list add a conditional statement:

```
SELECT 
  < some column(s) here >, 
  CASE WHEN is_closed = 1 
       THEN 'closed' 
       ELSE closing_time END AS CLOSING_TIME_OR_CLOSED
...
```

A tested example may be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/108c1/2

In contrast to the IF statement, the CASE statement is ANSI SQL meaning you can run your query on any RDBMS which implements the ANSI standard.

Comment: You're welcome. The query is correct based on what you've told us so far. Please edit your question to include sample data and DDL (data-definition language) statements. Alternatively provide an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: `23:00:00` is displayed because `is_closed` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Yes, but when `is_closed` is 1, I want `closing_time` to return the text "closed". Sorry for that, my fault :)

Comment: The quick fix is to add another condition to the CASE statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af2d0/3

Answer (score 1):

If `closing_time` is datatype TIME, then you could use an expression like this in your SELECT list:

```
SELECT IF(is_closed=1,'closed',TIME_FORMAT(closing_time,'%H:%i')) AS closing_time
```

Note that this expression will return a string (a VARCHAR datatype).

Comment: Thanks. but it still returns '23:00:00: with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Ng5/